# Cyclic rotation in Python

Tags: python

Task:

> An array `A` consisting of `N` integers is given. Rotation of the array means that each element is shifted right by one index, and the last element of the array is moved to the first place. For example, the rotation of array `A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]` is `[6, 3, 8, 9, 7]` (elements are shifted right by one index and 6 is moved to the first place).
>   The goal is to rotate array `A` `K` times; that is, each element of `A` will be shifted to the right `K` times.

I was wondering why this solution is not working?

```
def solution(A , K):
     old = A
     new = [0]*len(A)

     for i in range(K):
         new[0]=old[-1]
         new[1:] = old[:-1]
         old = new
     return new
```

Note: I have already solved the task, but I just don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: So what input did you give and what should it produce? What happens instead?

Comment: Put differently: *not working* doesn't tell us what happens instead, or what 'working' *looks* like.

Comment: The issue here is that `old = new` doesn't create a copy, so now `new is old` is true and `new[0] = old[-1]` means that the old value at `new[0]` (which is also the old value at `old[0]`) is now lost. See the duplicate on how to copy a list properly.

Comment: Exact the question I was looking for which is from `codility.com`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are simply assigning a new variable name to your `new` list when you do `old = new`. So whatever changes you now do to `new` will also be reflected in `old` because you simply created a new pointer to the same memory location of the `new` list. You should create a copy of the list so that you do not modify the original list. One way to do so is `old = new.copy()`

```
def solution(A , K):
     old = A
     new = [0]*len(A)
     for i in range(K):
         new[0]=old[-1]
         new[1:] = old[:-1]
         old = new.copy() # This was the problematic line
     return new

solution([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
# [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

solution([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
# [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```